# Find a relation s between numbers?

Tags: numbers

Please I need help to find the relations between these numbers , I hope if some can help me
3 22 25 30 49

1 12 27 42 47

22 37 43 44 45

8 21 25 38 50

Thank you

Comment: 3 (+19) 22 (+3) 25 (+5) 30 (+19) 49 so next number is 52

Comment: 8 (+13) 21 (+4) 25 (+13) 38 (+12) 50 (+13) 63. Next number is 4*4 or 12+8

Comment: No , I mean this are random numbers and I wanna to know the relations to expect the next row not the next number

Comment: For example the first row is 3 22 2530 49  the next row is 1 12 27 42 47  the third row 22 37 43 44 45 ..what will be the forth row ?